# Django foreign key and one-to-many relationship

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a basic ecommerce website, as a mean to learning django. I'm trying to build my models, so that there is a Category, a Product and Product Image class to store my data in. This is my models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('products:product_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'), )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('products:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products')
```

And this is my views.py:

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)

    product_img = Product.images.all()

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)

    return render(request, 'products/list.html', {'category': category, 'categories': categories, 'products': products, 'product_img': product_img})
```

I've seen similar post here on stack overflow, and have tried to do the same thing, but I still get the following error: AttributeError: 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: `product_img = Product.images.all()` is causing error. why are you using this ? could you please explain what are you trying to do here ?

Comment: If you need to show images the image for each product, you just need to send all model objects in context and then iterate them inside your template.

Comment: The point here is that `Product.images` is not what you should be referencing - that's an attribute of the class. Instead, you probably want the `images` manager on a particular `Product` instance. EG in a template, something like `{% for product in products %} {% for image in product.images.all %}<img src="{{ image.url }}" />{% endfor %} {% endfor %}` - that last bit is written from memory so I could easily have something wrong, the point is the `product.images.all` bit using one product at a time.

Comment: I'm trying to access the images set in the ProductImage class, that have a one-to-many relationship to the Product class. So I want to access these in my view and send it to the template. From what I can understand in the django docs, when setting a related name attribute, I can access the class using the Product.images.all(). So I want to sent all the model's objects to the view. @PeterDeGlopper How do I access the images for a particular product instance in the view?

Comment: Images don't have a one-to-many relationship to the Product *class*, they have a one-to-many relationship to individual products. Looking for all images for "the Product class" is like looking for all prime factors of "int". Given a product instance, `product.images.all()` is one way - `product.images` is a manager, like `Product.objects()` but with a different return type, so you can use it to build querysets.